# Access lotus notes object

Tags: javascript, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, activexobject

Can I access the lotus notes objects with javascript without using ActiveXObject Object. Does anyone know another method?

```
$('#btn').click(function SendScriptMail() {
     try {
        var Session = new ActiveXObject('Notes.NotesSession');
        var acti = new ActiveXObject("Notes.NotesUIWorkspace")
        var UserName = Session.UserName;
        alert(UserName);

        // Retrieve database from username 
        var MailDbName = UserName.substring(0, 1) 
                       + UserName.substring(UserName.indexOf(" ", 1) + UserName.length) 
                       + ".nsf"
        // Get database 
        var  Maildb = Session.GetDatabase("", MailDbName);
        acti.ComposeDocument("", "", "Memo");
     } catch (err) {
        alert(err.message);
     }
});
```

I need to access them client side, because on the server side (with c#)  i don't have registered any specified dll on it.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot access the Lotus objects from JavaScript without using ActiveX, but that does not necessarily mean you can't access Lotus Notes/Domino data. If your Domino server is release 8.5.3 or above, you can use a REST API called [Domino Data Service](http://infolib.lotus.com/resources/domino/8.5.3/doc/designer_up1/en_us/DominoDataService.html). It requires some server-side setup, and it can't do everything that the full object model can do, but it does provide read/write access to data.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not do that.
What you can do is to create Lotusscript agents on the server and call them from the web client using an Ajax call.
In this case you could pass the values for To, Subject and body in the email to the agent. That agent in turn would get the current user's name, create a mail and send it off.

Take a look at this presentation: http://www.slideshare.net/TexasSwede/ad102-break-out-of-the-box